# Retry async Task code using Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Having the code below in my data access class.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> QueryAsync(string sql, object param = null,
            CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int? commandTimeout = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
        {
            using (var connection = Connection)
            {
                var tokenSource = GetCancellationTokenSource(commandTimeout ?? CommandTimeoutDefault);
                Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> queryTask =
                    connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>(new CommandDefinition(sql, param, transaction,
                        commandTimeout ?? CommandTimeoutDefault, commandType, cancellationToken: tokenSource.Token));
                IEnumerable<TEntity> data = await queryTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
                tokenSource.Dispose();
                return data;
            }
        }
```

I want when a `SqlExeption` thrown to retry once. Have in mind that I can't apply RX to the application but only in this block of code.

I tried the below code, it looks like it is executing correctly and `Do` is logging in the Console Output but doesn't really invoke the `Catch` handler and I'm not sure if `Retry` handler is executed as well.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> QueryAsync(string sql, object param = null,
            CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text, int? commandTimeout = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
        {
            return await Observable.Defer(async () =>
            {
                using (var connection = Connection)
                {
                    var tokenSource = GetCancellationTokenSource(commandTimeout ?? CommandTimeoutDefault);
                    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> queryTask =
                        connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>(new CommandDefinition(sql, param, transaction,
                            commandTimeout ?? CommandTimeoutDefault, commandType, cancellationToken: tokenSource.Token));
                    IEnumerable<TEntity> data = await queryTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
                    tokenSource.Dispose();
                    return Observable.Return(data);
                }
            })
            .Catch<IEnumerable<TEntity>, SqlException>(source =>
           {
               Debug.WriteLine($"QueryAsync Exception {source}");
               return Observable.Return(new List<TEntity>());
           })
           .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
           .Retry(1)
           .Do(_ => Debug.WriteLine("Do QueryAsync"));
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see several potential problems with your code:

- separate the retry logic from the main logic, in a method called `QueryWithRetryAsync` for example. This is just a design problem, but a problem nonetheless
- don't `Catch` until *after* the `Retry`. Otherwise the `SqlException` will result in an empty list and the `Retry` operator will never see the exception
- I don't think the `Throttle` is necessary at all, since you only ever expect one value through the pipeline
- `Retry(1)` does not do what you think it does (this was a surprise to me, too). It seems the definition of "retry" includes the first invocation, so you need `Retry(2)`

Here is a standalone example that behaves the way you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pipeline = Observable
            .Defer(() => DoSomethingAsync().ToObservable())
            .Retry(2)
            .Catch<string, InvalidOperationException>(ex => Observable.Return("default"));

        pipeline
            .Do(Console.WriteLine)
            .Subscribe();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int invocationCount = 0;

    private static async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting DoSomethingAsync");

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        ++invocationCount;

        if (invocationCount == 2)
        {
            return "foo";
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```